# what is the best way to share a style folder among different projects?

Tags: css, github, sass, cdn

I'm working with different projects but all of them are sharing almost 90% of the styles. problem is that I have to add the styles folder to each project manually and then add the specific styles, the issue gets even bigger when the designer wants to change the default style folder because I have to change that property on each project folder. I was looking for a faster way to share only one style folder for all the projects but I'm not pretty sure of the best solution, this is what I've found so far:

-share the folder with a CDN: https://seo-hacker.com/implement-selfhosted-cdn-site-speed/

- Share CSS Between Related Projects With Git Subtrees: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2015/03/16/share-css-between-related-projects-with-git-subtrees/

Answer (score 1):

I would lean more towards the first approach. If you were to use git subtrees or git submodules, then you would still have to go to each project to update the shared css whenever it changes.

With a CDN, once you update that CSS, then it is live across all sites. The only problem with this is that you should have some sort of way of testing changes before you push them live and break every site out there.

Comment: I agree with that. In fact that is what we're doing and at the moment seems to work. Thanks